# Laravel REST api PUT / DELETE requests and Content-Type application/json header

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, http-headers, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 for an API and AngularJS for client side. Angular default request headers for `PUT` look something like this:

```
PUT /v1/contact/1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Authorization: Bearer token
```

Because all these 3 headers are not a default, the browser sends an option request before each operation to assure that these are accepted. 
I want to avoid this options request because of performance.

In order to achieve that I moved the token in the URL like `/v1/contact/1?token=token`

Another trick I used is that instead of `application/json` I send to Laravel `text/plain` in `Content-Type` and on Laravel side I overwrite the header in a middleware:

```
if ( $request->header('Content-Type') == 'text/plain' ) {
    $request->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
}
```

The last problem is that in order to make a `PUT` request, I make a `POST` request and because Laravel accepts `_method`, I put in all forms an input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

This field is recognized and is treated like a real `PUT` request. 
Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#form-method-spoofing

The only problem is that when I make the request like this because Laravel checks for `_method` parameter in the request before the middleware and the `Content-Type` is `text/plain`, it doesn't recognize the post data as an object.

I tried the same thing, only changing the `Content-Type` to `application/json` and it works without any issues.